# Get duplicate entry error message and use in if statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, duplicates

I would like to get the error message if a duplicate entry error happened with PDO.

this is the code I use where a duplicate entry is possible because id is a unique key:

```
$movetotable = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table` SELECT * FROM `$trashtable` WHERE id = :id");
$movetotable->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$movetotable->execute();
```

I hope it is possible with PHP PDO, I know this: `PDO::errorCode()` but I simply don't know how to use it in an if statement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you know, there might be an error, why not just do a check for duplicate entry, *before* you do your insert query?

Comment: check for dups by matching the id in the table and act accordingly from there

Comment: If you don't have to do any specific logic with duplicate entries, you can use INSERT IGNORE INTO or else you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option

Comment: @Philipp @Akin I cannot understand how to do that? Should I do that right after the **$movetotable = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table` SELECT * FROM `$trashtable` WHERE id = :id");** with PHP or is this possible in the query itself?

Comment: @Aruna **INSERT IGNORE INTO** is not an option because I don't want to lose the row. **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** is an option for me and I've tried that but only thing I get is a next error (syntax error). It says I didn't use on duplicate key update the right way. Do you know how to use it with the query in my question above?

Comment: Try in this format. INSERT INTO some_table(c1, c2, c3) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c2='b',c3='c' Here the column c1 is the key column

Comment: In your case this is a bulk insert.  I'm not sure how to use this with bulk insert. let me try and get back to you

Comment: Please try with following format. INSERT INTO some_table(c1, c2, c3) SELECT a, b, c from some_table_2 where b='z' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c2=some_table_2.b, c3=some_table_2.c;

Comment: I will try it out, thanks a lot already! @Aruna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO `$table` SELECT * FROM `$trashtable` WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute([$id]);
$id = $conn->lastInsertId();
if (!$id) {
    echo "a dupe!";
}
```

Comment: Hi @your-common-sense, I already fixed the duplicate problem, look at my answer below where I have another problem

Comment: you have not one but a whole lot of problems there. so you cannot say it's  solved. therefore better use my solution.

Comment: the problem with your solution is that I already tried that and it didn't work. If you would be so generous to explain what all the problems I have are?

Comment: Well tell me what to do then if you would like 

Comment: INSERT IGNORE INTO is not what I want because the row will be gone, the row should be added as a new row with a new id. Do you get that?

Comment: I answered the exact question that has been asked. you have your duplicate error and your if statement. If you don't like it, then you should blame the guy who wrote the question.

Comment: Well very nice of you but THIS is the error I get if I try your solution:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::insertId()

Comment: I'm sorry for not believing in your answer @your-common-sense, it worked after you updated it, thanks alot!